Going back to earlier version of shapefile that was saved in QGIS
By mistake I edited all cells of a table in QGIS. I saved it without knowing that and I need to go back to the earlier version, before it was saved. Is there a way to do it?

No, unless you have a backup copy of your ESRI Shapefile .dbf file.

if your on windows and previous versions is enabled https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch002024.htm but this is not a GIS question but a general IT one. suggest you look up 'NAS backup for home/business'

Hey thanks! I looked for the .dbf file and the modified date gives me some hope. Do you think i could use it to restore the previous info? Thanks  again.

@LadislaoFerrando the .dbf contains all the alphanumeric attributes' definitions and values of the features while the .shp contains the geometries of the features. Since you have only modified the alphanumeric attributes of the features and not their number or geometries, then you need to recover previous version of the .dbf file. If you cannot recover a previous version of the .dbf file, then you cannot recover the previous alphanumeric attributes values.
